# Uninstall cmake from centos to install it with yum

Tags: linux, centos, cmake, uninstallation

I would like to uninstall cmake from centos 6.5: I installed it manually and I have 3.0 version. I would like to uninstall it to install a previous version with yum. I deleted all cmake files as suggested in

```
http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Can_I_do_.22make_uninstall.22_with_CMake.3F
```

and I installed cmake with yum.
But when I call:

```
cmake ..
```

I receive the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
```

That means that previous installation is not clean. How can I clean it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to clear bash's  cache using:

```
hash -r
```

Reference: [SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables)

Answer (score 1):

For uninstall it. Try to use

> sudo yum remove cmake

or for cmake3

> sudo yum remove cmake3

Answer (score 0):

You can unistall cmake2 by the command

```
 sudo yum unistall cmake
```

or unistall cmake3 by

```
sudo yum uninstall cmake3
```

If "uninstall" doesn't work, try using "remove".